# how to get the td tags of table tag in appropriate manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am using `<table>`,`<tr>`,`<td>` tags in order to design a table.I designed a table but what happens is when the data coming from database is making the design of table extend which looks very bad.I will show an image.[image]

As you can see in the above image when the data is extending the table width is also extending but what i need is to extend the height of `<td>` tag but not width.I am posting the code below on what i did.

```
<div style="border-left: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 1px solid black;width:608px"><center><span style="font-size: 18px;"><b>Tax Invoice cum Delivery Challan &nbsp&nbsp&nbspBuyer/Seller Copy</b></span></center></div>
            <table align="center" style="border: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
               <tr>
               <td rowspan="3" style="border-right: 1px solid black; width: 300px">
               &nbsp<%= companyName%><br/>
                        &nbsp<%= branchLocationAddress%><br/>
                        <b>&nbspMobile Number: </b><%= mobileNumber%><br/>
                        <b>&nbspPhone Number: </b><%= landLineNumber%><br/>
                        <b>&nbspEmail ID: </b><%= emailID%>
               </td>
               <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspInvoice No</b><br/>
                   &nbsp<%= invoiceno%></td>
               <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspInvoice Date</b><br/>
                        &nbsp<%= invoicedate%></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>

               <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDelivery Note</b><br/>
                   &nbsp<%= deliverynote%></td>
               <td><b>&nbspMode Of Payment</b><br/>
                    &nbsp<%= termsofpayment%> </td>    
               </tr>
               <tr>

               <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspESugam No</b><br/>
                   &nbsp<%= esugamno%></td>
               <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspOther Reference</b></td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td rowspan="3" style="border-top: 1px solid black; width: 300px;border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspOrganizationName: </b><%= orgname%><br/>
                        <b>&nbspDelivery Address: </b><%= deliveryaddress%><br/>
                        <b>&nbspPhone No :</b><%= phone%></td>
                <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black"><b>&nbspBuyer Order No</b><br/>
                        &nbsp<%= buyerorderno%></td>  
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspBuy Date</b><br/>
                         &nbsp<%= buydate%></td>              
               </tr>
               <tr>

               <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDispatch Document No</b><br/> 
                        &nbsp<%= dispatchdocumentno%></td>
               <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDated</b><br/>
                      &nbsp<%= dated%></td>         
               </tr>
               <tr>

               <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDispatch Through</b><br/>
                          &nbsp<%= dispatchthrough%></td>
               <td><b>&nbspDestination</b><br/>
                        &nbsp<%= destination%></td>           
               </tr>
                </table> 
            <table align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

               <tr>
               <td rowspan="1" style="width:300px; border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspWorks Address: Same As Above</b></td>
               <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspTerms Of Delivery :- </b><%= termsofdelivery%><br/>
                      <b>&nbspAttention :- </b><%= attention %></td></tr>
                  </table>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use `word-break: break-all` in your CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It worked and looking great.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word-break: break-all
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Your div tag is being closed before table tag. Do it like this:-

```
    <div style="border-left: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 1px solid black;width:608px"><center><span style="font-size: 18px;"><b>Tax Invoice cum Delivery Challan &nbsp&nbsp&nbspBuyer/Seller Copy</b></span></center>
        <table align="center" style="border: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="3" style="border-right: 1px solid black; width: 300px">
           &nbsp<%= companyName%><br/>
                    &nbsp<%= branchLocationAddress%><br/>
                    <b>&nbspMobile Number: </b><%= mobileNumber%><br/>
                    <b>&nbspPhone Number: </b><%= landLineNumber%><br/>
                    <b>&nbspEmail ID: </b><%= emailID%>
           </td>
           <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspInvoice No</b><br/>
               &nbsp<%= invoiceno%></td>
           <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspInvoice Date</b><br/>
                    &nbsp<%= invoicedate%></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>

           <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDelivery Note</b><br/>
               &nbsp<%= deliverynote%></td>
           <td><b>&nbspMode Of Payment</b><br/>
                &nbsp<%= termsofpayment%> </td>    
           </tr>
           <tr>

           <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspESugam No</b><br/>
               &nbsp<%= esugamno%></td>
           <td style="border-top: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspOther Reference</b></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td rowspan="3" style="border-top: 1px solid black; width: 300px;border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspOrganizationName: </b><%= orgname%><br/>
                    <b>&nbspDelivery Address: </b><%= deliveryaddress%><br/>
                    <b>&nbspPhone No :</b><%= phone%></td>
            <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black"><b>&nbspBuyer Order No</b><br/>
                    &nbsp<%= buyerorderno%></td>  
            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspBuy Date</b><br/>
                     &nbsp<%= buydate%></td>              
           </tr>
           <tr>

           <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDispatch Document No</b><br/> 
                    &nbsp<%= dispatchdocumentno%></td>
           <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDated</b><br/>
                  &nbsp<%= dated%></td>         
           </tr>
           <tr>

           <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspDispatch Through</b><br/>
                      &nbsp<%= dispatchthrough%></td>
           <td><b>&nbspDestination</b><br/>
                    &nbsp<%= destination%></td>           
           </tr>
            </table> 
        <table align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

           <tr>
           <td rowspan="1" style="width:300px; border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspWorks Address: Same As Above</b></td>
           <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;"><b>&nbspTerms Of Delivery :- </b><%= termsofdelivery%><br/>
                  <b>&nbspAttention :- </b><%= attention %></td></tr>
              </table>  </div>
```

It will solve your problem. If you have any other problem then tell me. Thanks

Comment: word-break:break-all does the trick.When i use <div> as you said it is becoming even worst.

Answer (score -1):

your div is closed before the table starts. Wrap your table within the div.

```
<div style="border-left: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 1px solid black;width:608px"><center><span style="font-size: 18px;"><b>Tax Invoice cum Delivery Challan &nbsp&nbsp&nbspBuyer/Seller Copy</b></span></center>

<table>[..]</table>  
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: On the codes basis you have provided it is working quite well as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/qtte4f53/ Maybe you have decided to use the other suggestion provided, but I can not really see why there should not be more than one correct answer.